# WebView Long press crashes with AppCompatActivity but works fine with ActionBarActivity. Why?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have an Application with one Activity and multiple fragments which load certain child views and a WebView to display an HTML file.

WebViews is inside the fragment layout. Now when The MainActivity is extending **AppCompatActivity** the app crashes at long press ( to highlight text) but using **ActionBarActivity** the app works for and the contextual menu appears.

I have no clue why this is happening but I will appreciate any pointers.

This the log I get :

```
    02-08 16:48:53.290 30263-30263/com.amr.demo A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(236)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
```

The rest of the crash is (it was too long to add in the question) [here](https://gist.github.com/amrfarid140/4e1c2364cc4d90e4ba28ac964b54bf4c)

And here is the **fragment** Java file :

```
package fragment;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.ineqe.able.library.AbleWebView;
import com.ineqe.able.library.MainActivity;
import com.ineqe.able.library.MyApplication;
import com.ineqe.able.library.R;

public class NewsItemFrag extends Fragment {
    private String video_id;
    private SharedPreferences sp2;
    private Intent mainmenu;
    private AbleWebView wv;
    private SharedPreferences sp3;
    private String link;
    private String header;
    private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private int groupPosition;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sp3 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("textSize", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int size = sp3.getInt("textSize", 17);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();

        webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(size);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int i = item.getItemId();
        if (i == R.id.share) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.newsitem, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);
        wv = (AbleWebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        wv.setLongClickable(false);

        Bundle args = getArguments();

        String image = args.getString("image", "");
        String web = args.getString("web", "");
        groupPosition = args.getInt("gposition", 1);
        LinearLayout Musicplayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.musicp);
        RelativeLayout Rlayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.buttons);
        Musicplayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Rlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        link = args.getString("link", "");
        header = args.getString("header_image", "");
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", web, "text/html", "charset=UTF-8", null);
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.topimage);
        sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("sharedpref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        img.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/" + header, null, getActivity().getPackageName())));
        WebSettings w = wv.getSettings();
        w.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        w.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        view.requestFocus();
        view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    MainActivity.position = groupPosition + 1;
                    sharedpreferences.edit().putBoolean("back", true).apply();
                    mainmenu = new Intent(getActivity(), ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getMainActivity());
                    mainmenu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(mainmenu);


                    getActivity().finish();


                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?  Probably something to do with the Toolbar.

Comment: The stack trace shows an internal chrome error. I will update the question to include it.

Comment: @Submersed I have added it now. I can't understand anything from it though.